# From php multidimensional array get html ul li ul li... with less loops (using less system resources)

Tags: php, arrays

Have php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NumberRenamed] => 2
            [TopicName] => Contacts
            [UpperLevelNumberRenamed] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NumberRenamed] => 3
            [TopicName] => Legal services
            [UpperLevelNumberRenamed] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NumberRenamed] => 1
            [TopicName] => Services
            [UpperLevelNumberRenamed] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
           [NumberRenamed] => 4
           [TopicName] => Accounting services
           [UpperLevelNumberRenamed] => 1
        )
 )
```

From the array want to get html like this

```
<div>

<ul class="mnav-ul">
<li class="mnav-ul-li">Contacts</li>
<li class="mnav-ul-li">Services
  <ul class="mnav-ul-ul">
  <li>Legal services</li>
  <li>Accounting services</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

I did

1) created one array of top level menu items, another array with sub level menu(s) items and array that contains `UpperLevelNumberRenamed` of sub level menu(s) items

```
foreach ( $navigation as $k_navigation => $v_navigation ){

if( $v_navigation['UpperLevelNumberRenamed'] == 0 ){
$top_level_navigation[] = $v_navigation;
}

else if( $v_navigation['UpperLevelNumberRenamed'] != 0 ){

$sub_level_navigation[] = $v_navigation;
$sublev_upper_level_number_renamed[] = $v_navigation['UpperLevelNumberRenamed'];

}//else if( $v_navigation['UpperLevelNumberRenamed'] != 0 ){


}//foreach ( $navigation as $k_navigation => $v_navigation ){
```

2) then loop at first through top level items array and inside each loop again loop through sub level menu(s) items

```
$main_navigation = '
<div>
<ul class="mnav-ul">
';

foreach ( $top_level_navigation as $k_top_level_navigation => $v_top_level_navigation ){

if( !in_array( $v_top_level_navigation['NumberRenamed'], $sublev_upper_level_number_renamed ) ) {
$main_navigation .= '<li class="mnav-ul-li">'. $v_top_level_navigation['TopicName']. '</li>';
}

else if( in_array( $v_top_level_navigation['NumberRenamed'], $sublev_upper_level_number_renamed ) ) {
$main_navigation .= '<li class="mnav-ul-li">'. $v_top_level_navigation['TopicName']. '';

$main_navigation .= '<ul class="mnav-ul-ul">';

foreach ( $sub_level_navigation as $k_sub_level_navigation => $v_sub_level_navigation ){

if( $v_top_level_navigation['NumberRenamed'] == $v_sub_level_navigation['UpperLevelNumberRenamed'] ){
$main_navigation .= '<li>'. $v_sub_level_navigation['TopicName']. '</li>';
}

}//foreach ( $sub_level_navigation as $k_sub_level_navigation => $v_sub_level_navigation ){

$main_navigation .= '</ul></li>';

}//if( ( in_array( $v_top_level_navigation['NumberRenamed'], $sublev_upper_level_number_renamed ) ) {

}//foreach ( $navigation as $k_navigation => $v_navigation ){

$main_navigation .= '</ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>';

echo $main_navigation;
```

Can get what i need. But too many loops (possible waste of system resources). Is it possible to get the same result with less loops (using less system resurces)?

Comment: Note that, unless you have humongous arrays, the amount of system resources 'wasted' by doing multiple loops is neglectable.